# In Maven how do I build the modules, but not the aggregator project itself?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I would like to build modules via an aggregator, but avoid the aggregator project being built itself. In my use-case, the aggregator is a dummy wrapper simply used for grouping together a build, and has no significance as a project in its own right

Is it possible to remove the aggregator from the reactor somehow?

Comment: There is nothing to build in a pom project. So there is little overhead. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I'm building my own recursive local build plugin, which builds an intermediate pom.xml containing modules for (recursively) -SNAPSHOT in-house dependencies. I don't want the wrapper pom to feature in the log output and confuse users of my plugin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way of doing that. But I believe your real problem is that this aggregator artifact is deployed to remote repository along with other modules and it doesn't make sense, as you said. What I recommend then is to set `<skip>true</skip>` for `maven-deploy-plugin` in aggregator's `pom.xml` to disable its deploy, like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) supports this since version 2.4.

Comment: Very very bad. Don't do that! You modules depent on their parent. If some client will pull your modules, it will require their parent. It won't work because the parent cannot be resolved from your repo. Beside that, the config of that plugin will be inherited. Such a config should be done very very wisely.

Comment: We're talking here about modules' aggregator, not parent. Aggregator usually == parent, but not always!

Comment: Just a heads-up: This will not work together with deployAtEnd.